# Unable configure Alerts and Actions in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using a Docker Compose file for ELK setup and using the latest version (above 7) for Kibana. Now I set the `xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey` parameter in the `kibana.yml` so that I can use the alert and actions feature. But even after that I'm not able to create alert. Can anyone help me please?

I generated 32 character encryption key using [Python uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) module.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have tried using the environment variable in my docker-compose.yml file as

```
kib01:
image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${VERSION}
container_name: kib01
depends_on: {"es01": {"condition": "service_healthy"}}
ports:
  - 5601:5601
environment:
  SERVERNAME: localhost
  ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://es01:9200
  ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://es01:9200
  XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY: "743787217A45432B462D4A614EF35266"
volumes:
  - /var/elasticsearch/config/certs:$CERTS_DIR
networks:
  - elastic
```

We have changed the string format of xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in to environment variable format XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY by replacing . with _ and all caps.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/57773 the environment variable `XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY` was missing in the kibana config. In Feb 2020 it was merged and is now working.

The encryption key `XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY` has to be 32 characters or longer. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/using-kibana-with-security.html

A working configuration could look like this:

```yaml
...
  kibana:
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.0.0-rc2
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ...
      - SERVER_PUBLICBASEURL=https://kibana.stackoverflow.com/
      - XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY=a7a6311933d3503b89bc2dbc36572c33a6c10925682e591bffcab6911c06786d
      - ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with mounting the file, I opted for the environment variables in my docker-compose file.

```
services:
  kibana:
    ...
    environment:
      ...
      XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY: abcd...
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it